# Why are colors messed up on video playback (Nvidia bug)?

Tags: nvidia, video, colors

It's been since Ubuntu 11.04 that a regression appeared which causess all video playback (which uses hardware acceleration) to have all the colors messed up, at least on NVidia graphics cards. The issue was already widely known when I was apparently (and surprisingly) the first one to report it in Launchpad, and not only it hasn't been fixed but it hasn't got the least attention: it hasn't been assigned nor has it even been decided its "importance" (which is not very difficult to decide).
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/862831

There are workarounds for local video file playback (applying color settings to compensate for the wrong colors) but they must be done for every player, and not all players have this option; plus for other things such as video streaming from web (e.g. YOUTUBE) there's no workaround other than disabling video hardware acceleration, which has an unacceptable performance cost.

The question is, is this being addressed or doen't anybody give a **** that you can't use Ubuntu for anything video-related?

Comment: Listen, ranting isn't going to bring you anywhere. I'm watching a Youtube video as I'm typing this without any problems, so stating Ubuntu is useless for anything video-related is nonsense.

You shouldn't forget that Nvidia's graphics drivers are closed-source and hence maintained by Nvidia inc. Ubuntu is powerless in terms of fixing their bugs.

Comment: did you tried using `x-swat` [repo](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) to get for flexible graphics driver?

Comment: somebody changed the title of my post. I wasn't asking why, I already know why (because some piece of software is broken). I was asking whether there is any chance that this will be addressed in a near future, either by NVidia or by Canonical

Answer (score 1):

1. Bugs are off-topic on AskUbuntu.
2. This a bug reported **by you** and confirmed by **one** other person.
3. Nvidia is one of the top two discrete graphics cards companies.
4. If a significant percentage of users were having this problem, surely there would be more than one confirmation.
5. Therefore, this is a problem localized to you, probably to your hardware (graphics card, monitor, etc.)

Comment: 2: the issue has been described in plenty of sites even before I reported it on Launchpad. That launchpad fails to track it down doesn't mean it doesn't exist. 3: that's precisely why it seems to me embarassing that it doesn't get fixed. 4: in a lot of forums you can find people discussing this issue. Many are happy just tweaking the color settings of their favourite player and/or disabling hadrware acceleration 5: sure, the monitor.